# CVXPY shows warning "Objective contains too many subexpressions" and takes a long time to compile the problem

Tags: python, cvxpy

I have tried to solve a simple unconstrained quadratic problem with CVXPY, which solves the problem as expected, as long as the matrix size is small enough. The following code shows a simplified version of my optimization problem, which takes about 12 seconds to compile and solve.

```py
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cp
from scipy.linalg import dft
import time as time


start_time = time.time()

N_r = 8
N_t = 1
N_s = 10

x = np.random.randint(2, size = N_s*N_r*N_t)

H = dft(N_s*N_r*N_t)*1j
H_H = H.conj().T

err = np.random.random(N_r)
Err = np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(N_s)), np.kron(np.diag(np.ones(N_t)), np.diag(err)))

y = H_H@Err@H@x

var = cp.Variable(shape = (N_r), complex = True)
Err_est = cp.kron(np.diag(np.ones(N_s)), cp.kron(np.diag(np.ones(N_t)), cp.diag(var)))

res = cp.sum_squares(H_H@Err_est@H@x - y)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Minimize(res))
prob.solve(solver = cp.CVXOPT, verbose = True)

print(f'Result: {np.abs(err-var.value)}')
print(f'\nProcessing duration: {time.time()-start_time:.2f} seconds')
```

Changing the size of matrix **Err** by adjusting the variable N_t = 2, increases the compiling and execution time to 200 seconds, where the solver time in both cases remains at 30 ms. This sinificant increase in time compiling time can also be verified for increasing the variable N_r or N_s.

With this change, CVXPY shows the warnings:

1. UserWarning: Objective contains too many subexpressions. Consider vectorizing your CVXPY code to speed up compilation.
   warnings.warn("Objective contains too many subexpressions. "
2. UserWarning: Constraint #0 contains too many subexpressions. Consider vectorizing your CVXPY code to speed up compilation.
   warnings.warn(f"Constraint #{i} contains too many subexpressions. "

in the console.
Digging into the python code of CVXPY revealed that in the debug_tools.py file a MAX_NODES = 10_000 count is set, which is the limit within the "Problem" class for throwing the stated warnings. Sadly I do not understand how the nodes are counted and how I can reduce them, because this might be the solution to the problem. The solution is obviously not to supress the warning and rather the reduction of compiling time, which is necessary for implementations with N_r = 20 and N_t = 10.

Notwithstanding, I also implemented the same optimization problem in Matlab and used CVX with the standard SDPT3 solver. Even though, the problem remains the same for Matlab, the time to solve the problem is significant shorter than in the python implementation.

```matlab
tic
N_r = 8;
N_t = 1;
N_s = 10;

x = randi([0 1], N_s*N_r*N_t,1);

H = dftmtx(N_s*N_r*N_t)*1i;
H_H = H';

err = randn(1,N_r);
Err = kron(diag(ones(1,N_s)), kron(diag(ones(N_t,1)), diag(err)));

y = H_H*Err*H*x;

cvx_begin
    variable varx(N_r)
    Err_est = kron(diag(ones(1,N_s*N_t)),diag(varx));
    
    minimize(sum_square_abs(H_H*Err_est*H*x - y,1)) 
cvx_end

disp('Result: '); 
disp(err.'-varx)

toc
```

The ultimate questions from my side are:

1. Why is the Matlab implementation so much faster?
2. How are the nodes calculated?
3. How can I reduce the amount of nodes by maintaining the problem?
4. What can be done to avoid this problem in the future?
5. How can I reduce the compiling time and achieve Matlab like compiling speed?

I tried a lot of things and searched the internet for a solution, but nothing suited to this problem. In addition, this is the first time I post some code questions in the internet, so please be nice and forgive me the mistakes in fomulating the problem.

Edit: Replacing the `cp.sum_squares()` function with `cp.norm()` reduces the compiling duration significantly in the `N_t = 1` case from 12 seconds to <0.3 seconds and in the `N_t = 2` case from 200 seconds to 1.4 seconds. However, this improvement is appreciated, but not as fast as the Matlab cvx version especially for large problem sizes. For example: setting  `N_r = 16`
and `N_t = 8` the compilation took about 4000 seconds with cvxpy, while Matlab solves this in 11 seconds. Furthermore, for large problems the kernel in python tends to crash.

Edit2: I generated an issue in the [CVXPY Github repository](https://github.com/cvxpy/cvxpy/issues/2205), where my problem was addressed. However, the problem can't be solved with the current and upcoming version of CVXPY and I am searching for alternative optimization solutions or simply using Matlab for the optimization task.

Comment: One can only guess that it is your use of composite cp.kron that generates a large model. Why don't you do the same as in the CVX code, that is use associativity to first take the product of the first two constant arguments and only have one layer of cp.kron in the expression.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Thank your for your response. Sorry for the inconsistency between the Matlab and Python code. I've tried numerous things and also reduced the problem to the single cp.kron, but this does not affect the compiling time. I have even reformulated the optimization matrix to `Err_est = cp.diag(cp.hstack([var,np.ones(72)]))`. Without any doubt this does not describe my optimization problem, but has the same size and number of variables. Sadly, this altered code is not compiled faster then in the origial post.

Comment: All I can suggest is to report an issue on cvxpy's github.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will report that issue later this day.